# Change "dd.mm.yyyy" to "mm/dd/yyyy" VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I know "dd.mm.yyyy" is not formatted as date within Excel, and this conversion part is what is getting to me. I have "31.3.2019" within .cell("C5") and want it to convert within the same cell (replace it) with a new formatting of "3/31/2019". I keep on getting an 'out of range' error and I am not sure where my mistake is.

Below is what I have tried:

```
Sub DivestitureTemplate_ChangeDateFormat()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range
Dim str() As String
    Set rng = Range("C5:C3000")

With Worksheets("Divestiture Template")
For Each rng In Selection
    str = Split(rng.Value, ".")
    rng.Value = DateSerial(2000 + str(4), str(2), str(0))
Next rng
Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With

End Sub
```

Change format of ("C5:C3000") from 31.3.2019 to 3/31/2019 -- it can be continuous, but starting at "C5" as this is an automated report and this is below a specified header. I think I have been looking at this, scripting all day and loosing my head over this for no reason.

Comment: `DateSerial(2000 + str(4), str(2), str(0))` will raise that error depending on the size of the `str` array. FYI: `Split("31.3.2019", ".")` will give an array like `(31, 3, 2019)`.

Comment: So based on your input, `str(4)` will always be out of bounds. Also, you're assigning a `rng` variable, and then ignoring that in favor of iterating `Selection`. That probably means you're not iterating the cells in C5:C3000, which would possibly give unexpected results or errors.

Comment: Still boggles my mind that anyone anywhere would want to use anything other than the internationally unambiguous ISO-standard `yyyy-mm-dd` date format.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon SAP EU systems like the format I am trying to fix :(

Comment: It might have something to do with your Windows regional settings - make the regional settings use the ISO format, Excel will default to the same, and presumably (ok, *hopefully*) SAP client will too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get real dates in the column, try:

```
Sub DivestitureTemplate_ChangeDateFormat()
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, d As Date
    Set rng = Worksheets("Divestiture Template").Range("C5:C3000")

    For Each cell In rng
        With cell
            arr = Split(.Text, ".")
            .Value = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
            .NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy"
        End With
    Next cell
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

```
Sub DivestitureTemplate_ChangeDateFormat()
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, d As Date
    Dim arr
    Set rng = Worksheets("Divestiture Template").Range("C5:C3000")

    For Each cell In rng
        With cell
            arr = Split(.Text, ".")
            .Value = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
            .NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy"
        End With
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a "Variable not defined" error at --- arr = Split(.Text, ".")

Comment: @AntyA that's `Option Explicit` doing its job (kudos!) - simply add `Dim arr As Variant` somewhere in that procedure scope, should work.

Comment: Not even sure why I asked this, you can see how my work day is going today xD --- although the script executes perfectly, I get a "Script is out of Range" syntax error at ".Value = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))"

Not sure why, but thanks for the help

Comment: @AntyA That's probably because one cell doesn't follow the input format you expect (i.e., `dd.mm.yyyy`). Therefore, when you `Split` its value, it doesn't produce an array with 3 elements.